# How to get value from array in array?

Tags: php, arrays

Original code lets you select 1 event.
Each ID contained a workshop titel, place and hour.

```
$event_hour_details = TT_DB::getEventHours(array(
                'event_hours_id' => $event_hour_id,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
            ));

$event_hour_details = $workshop_ids[0][0];

$event_hour_details->column_title
```

I want to select multiple events
So I made an array in JS and converted it into a string. 
ID's are sent from JS ( xxx,xxx,xxx,... ) to PHP where I explode it into an array

```
$workshop_ids = explode(',', $event_hour_id);


foreach ($workshop_ids as $workshop_id){
  $event_hour_details = TT_DB::getEventHours(array(
    'event_hours_id' => $workshop_id,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
            ));
        }


$event_hour_details = $workshop_ids[0][0];??

$event_hour_details->column_title??
```

How can I get all event titles to display?
Sry for my lack of knowledge

---

Update #2

Oh, I thought TT_DB::getEventHours(array()) created an array.

```
 foreach($workshop_ids as $event_details) { 
$event_data .= "Workshop: " . $event_details . "<br />"; }
```

Gives me the workshop ID's. 
But with

```
foreach($event_hour_details_array as $event_hour_details) { 
echo $event_hour_details->column_title."<br>"; }
```

The value returns empty for some reason?

---

Update 3

Debugging code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start] => 09.00
                    [end] => 17.00
                    [description_1] => Je sterker voordoen dan je bent?
                    [description_2] => Vrijdag 18 Oktober
                    [event_title] => Exoskeletons / VR
                    [column_title] => Willemen Construct en Eifage Benelux
                    [booking_count] => 10
                    [available_places] => 150
                    [slots_per_user] => 30
                    [current_user_booking_count] => 0
                    [current_guest_booking_count] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start] => 09.00
                    [end] => 17.00
                    [description_1] => tooltip Tectum
                    [description_2] => Vrijdag 18 Oktober
                    [event_title] => ?
                    [column_title] => Tectum
                    [booking_count] => 4
                    [available_places] => 150
                    [slots_per_user] => 30
                    [current_user_booking_count] => 0
                    [current_guest_booking_count] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

@Adder Ok found the print :D

Comment: Can you post some real PHP code? It looks like you get different results from wherever you load the data. Maybe also the code of "getEventHours" would help.

Comment: !Show us exact code where you have problem leave rest!

Comment: You probably want to make $event_hour_details an array and add entries to it inside that foreach loop, instead of overwriting it every time. (You did not show where you make any actual _output_, so I assume that comes later? Then you will have to loop over your new array in that position now.)

Comment: I've edited the post as best as I could.
Hope I'm making sense in what I'm trying to to.

Comment: Please add debugging code, see the answer and comment to my answer.

Comment: Please check the changes in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array. `$array[]` means append to the array.
It seems `TT_DB::getEventHours` returns an array of objects. I took this into account in the following code.

```
$workshop_ids = explode(',', $event_hour_id);

$event_hour_details_array = array();
foreach ($workshop_ids as $workshop_id){
    $event_hour_details_array[] = TT_DB::getEventHours(array(
        'event_hours_id' => $workshop_id,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        ));
}

//for debugging
echo "<pre>".print_r($event_hour_details_array, true)."</pre>";

foreach($event_hour_details_array as $event_hour_details) {
    foreach($event_hour_details as $hours) {
        echo $hours->column_title." ".$hours->start."-".$hours->end."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `'TT_DB::getEventHours` creates an object from an array with two parameters in it.  Please put a `print_r($event_hour_details_array);` in the code for debugging and tell me the output.

Comment: I can't thank you enough.

This works like a charm! I'll buy you a coffee some day ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Please try as this, may  be help you:
 $data=[];
    foreach ($workshop_ids as $workshop_id){
             $abc[]= array(
    'name_your_column' =>workshop_id
    'name_your_column' =>workshop_id
    )
            }